# GetListItems() causes a 401 error but Checkout() works

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to get the contents of a Sharepoint 2007 list via web service.  I'm using this code, which I mostly copied from [the MSDN page for GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace testGetListItems
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sharepoint.Lists listService = new sharepoint.Lists();
            listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

            XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
            XmlNode ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
            XmlNode ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");

            ndQueryOptions.InnerXml =
                "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" +
                "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>";
            ndViewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name='Field1' />    <FieldRef Name='Field2'/>";
            ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name='Field1'/>" +
                "<Value Type='Number'>5000</Value></Gt><Gt><FieldRef Name='Field2'/>" +
                "<Value Type=        'DateTime'>2003-07-03T00:00:00</Value></Gt></And></Where>";
            try
            {
                bool checkoutResult=listService.CheckOutFile("http://sharepoint/sites/mysite/myFile.xlsx", "false", null);
                XmlNode ndListItems =
                    listService.GetListItems("Test List", null, ndQuery,
                    ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
            }

            catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message:\n" + ex.Message + "\nDetail:\n" +
                    ex.Detail.InnerText +
                     "\nStackTrace:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `CheckOutFile()` works correctly.  But the `GetListItems()` call gives me this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Web.Services.dll
Additional information: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

I don't understand why `CheckOutFile()` succeeds but `GetListItems()` fails, especially because the document that I'm checking out is in the list that's being accessed by `GetListItems()`.

Comment: Sometime ago I tried to build a tool to export SharePoint 2007 lists and also got the same error from time to time. I was using WCF on the client side.

Comment: Try using the list GUID instead of the display name.

Comment: @NitinChhajer, I tried it with the list GUID and got the same result.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: This worked in a test console app, but not in my main application.  Leaving this answer up for now, but I'm not going to accept it until I get this fixed.

---

It turned out the problem was with the URL of the web service.  Even though I had added it as:

```
http://sharepoint/sites/mySite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
```

the **app.config** file had it listed as:

```
http://sharepoint/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
```

This remained a problem even after I deleted the reference and re-added it; I had to change the **app.config** contents manually.  Once I'd done so, the `GetListItems()` call succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You must set a user and password who can get the items in the library/list this way (for me it works, you could try):

```
public string GetIDFromList(string parameter)
    {
        string retorno = "";

        try
        {
            string path = "http://www.test.com/web/";

            // Reference to the SharePoint Lists web service:
            WSSharePointCSCLists.Lists listsWS = new WSSharePointCSCLists.Lists();

            listsWS.Url = path + "_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

            listsWS.Credentials = GetUserCredential();

            string listName = "MyList";
            string viewName = "";
            //string webID;
            string rowLimit = "500";

            // Web ID:
            webID = "098304-9098asdf-qwelkfj-eoqiula";                    


            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

            // Query em CAML (SharePoint):
            XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");

            XmlNode ndViewFields =
                        xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
            XmlNode ndQueryOptions =
                        xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");

            ndQueryOptions.InnerXml =
                        "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" +
                        "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>" +
                        "<ViewAttributes Scope=\"RecursiveAll\" />";

            ndViewFields.InnerXml = @"<FieldRef Name='Title' />                        
                                        <FieldRef Name='ID' />";


            string caml =
                String.Format(
                            @"<Where>
                                <Contains>
                                    <FieldRef Name='MyColumn' />
                                    <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>           
                                </Contains>                                    
                            </Where>",
                    parameter);

            ndQuery.InnerXml = caml;

            XmlNode retornoWS = listsWS.GetListItems(listName, null, ndQuery,
                                                         ndViewFields, rowLimit,
                                                         ndQueryOptions, webID);

            retorno = retornoWS.InnerXml;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return retorno;
    }


    public NetworkCredential GetUserCredential()
    {
        return new System.Net.NetworkCredential("<username>",
                                                "<password>",
                                                "<domain>");
    }
```